# How to test a unexported (private) function in go (golang)?

Tags: unit-testing, go

I was interested in creating unit test for "unexported (private) functions" in go. However, its basically really hard to create unit tests form them in the test package because I have to make them "public". Which in the end, defeats the whole point of them being private. The point is that these helper function help modularize and now that they are modular, it would be nice to be able to create unit tests for them without making them available to everyone except the testing package, nice they are not functions that should be accessed or used by anyone else except the testing suite or the actual package itself.

Any suggestions? Is it possible to **only** export to its own package and 1 additional package or something of that sort in go?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

create a test file within the package

library_test.go

```
package mypkg

func TestPrivateStruct(t *testing.T){
  pf := private{ "Private Field" }
  ....
}
```

library.go

```
package mypkg

type private struct {
  privateField string
}
```

`go test mypkg -v` will run your Tests with your private struct

Comment: But this would mean that all of my unit tests are not under the `test` package, right? So running go test on the test directory would no longer give a complete test of my library, right?

Comment: @CharlieParker -- Yes, but that's the standard in Go. You mix _test files and non-_test files in a package, and test some/path/packagename, not some/path/packagename/test or some/path/tests/packagename.

Comment: @twotwowo fair enough. However, its annoying to have to go to every dir to run each go test. Is it possible to run **all** of the tests through some kind of command or a Make file or something of that sort?

Comment: Ah, good question. The go tools support a `...` wildcard, so you can `go test github.com/yourname/yourrepo/...` to test every package in there. (Or things like `go test github.com/yourname/...` or `go test crypto/...` if you're so moved.)

Comment: @CharlieParker `go test ./...` run all the tests. Remember to use `--tags` if you need.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you "litter your [package] public surface with hundreds of test functions" (source: https://medium.com/@thrawn01/why-you-should-never-test-private-methods-f822358e010). Effectively, every Test* method you write now becomes exported with the package.

Comment: @teuber789 , Test entities (including functions) declared in files ending in `_test.go` are not exportable (i.e. accessible) to other packages.

They are only available within the directory in which they are declared. You can check this in practice :)

Answer (score 24):

if you want to use pkg_test name as a package name for test and still test unexported field a simple trick could be create export_test.go file in your package with package name pkg then export your unexported field in there for example

file code.go

```
package pkg 

func getFunc(){}
```

file export_test.go

```
package pkg 
var GetFunc = getFunc
```

file code_test.go

```
package pkg_test
func TestGetFunc(t *testing.T) {
    testFunc:=pkg.GetFunc

    //check your test scenario here

}
```

note that all these files are in the same folder

the solution is inspired from [here](https://medium.com/@robiplus/golang-trick-export-for-test-aa16cbd7b8cd)

Comment: This is the correct way of doing it. Otherwise you either have to export things just for tests or have black box tests sharing the same package as the code to be tested.

Comment: you are not exporting a method, just a function

Comment: The part about "note that all these files are in the same folder" cannot be stressed enough. I spent quite a bit of time fiddling with this before noticing the line. Thank you for your post, it was very helpful!

Comment: @JoulinRouge : I am late here but to test method you can use above approach with var ExposedPrivateMethod = (*SomeStruct).privateMethod in you test package, and you can use it in _test package like ExposedPrivateMethod(*SomeStruct, 1, 2) for testing that method.

Comment: Won't `GetFunc` be accessible in other packages? If yes, then it defeats the purpose of having the private function in the first place.

Comment: @mrpandey ,  no. The `GetFunc` function will only be available to tests in this directory, i.e. to test packages `pkg` and `pkg_test` because the `GetFunc` function is declared in a file ending in `_test.go`.

Comment: @Vadim now I noticed! This is brilliant. So basically, export in a _test.go file but the package name should be the same.

Answer (score 9):

First, you can have both types of tests in the same location as your package by using the package name for internal tests (eg **mypkg**) and using the same package name with "_test" appended for "external" tests (eg **mypkg_test**). Both types of tests must be in files whose name ends in "_test.go".

BUT, the whole point of unit tests is to test the "external interface" (ie public functions) to your package. That is unit tests should always be "white box" tests (see [White Box Testing](http://devmethodologies.blogspot.com.au/2013/11/unit-tests-white-box-testing.html)). That way you can refactor your code and your tests won't break.

Of course, sometimes you want to check internal consistency, which is not possible through the "external interface". For that I have found assertions invaluable. Another possibility would be to add public "diagnostic" function(s) with names that indicate that they are not for normal use.

Comment: _with names that indicate that they are not for normal use._ --- at which point you're just accessing internals from your unit tests, but through a layer of indirection which is accessible from callers to boot. If you do this, it's a crystal clear sign 'external-only' testing doesn't cut it for your purpose. Might as well call a spade a spade and go internal.

Comment: unit tests are *not* only for public functions. Often a public interface could result in a myriad of different expectations resulting from combinations of private functions. it's a lot easier and safer to have a unit test for the smaller single purpose functions. You still want to test public ones as well obviously.

Answer (score 3):

As of [Go 1.5](https://golang.org/doc/go1.5) you can use internal packages for shared functions within a package without having to expose them to outside callers.

Simply create a package named `internal` inside you package, move your shared functions into files inside the `internal` package and expose them as public functions. Then you can create test files for these functions as you would normally, using the `internal_test` for the package.

For example:

```
project/
└── domain/
    ├── logic.go
    ├── logic_test.go
    ├── wisdom.go
    ├── wisdom_test.go
    └── internal/
        ├── shared.go
        └── shared_test.go
```

Only code within the `domain` package would be able to see and access the functions exposed inside the `internal` package. For a more in depth description, see the [proposal](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1e8kOo3r51b2BWtTs_1uADIA5djfXhPT36s6eHVRIvaU/edit) or look at the [go source code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/5631c4b3bfd71aae7cbdd7f35f63de7f89639d1e/src/cmd/buildid/buildid.go#L35).

Comment: It's a good suggestion to use `internal` packages, but sometimes the function doesn't need to be shared, just tested.